# Automating password checking using httpclient

Tags: java, httpclient

Right now I'm having some major issues with writing a simple portscanner / password checker for a work security project.

My basic goal is to write a quick little tool that opens up a text file, Scans on ports 21,23,80,502, and 8080 then simply writes the returned http status to a file (200, 404, whatever)

So far I've been trying to do this using httpclient and I've had very poor results.

My code goes something like this

```
 public static void doHosts() throws Exception{
        String filename = "C:\\test.txt";
        String ip = "";
        String port[] = {"21", "23", "80", "502", "8080"};
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\scan.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((ip = br.readLine()) != null) {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(ip);
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("blah", "blah");
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()), creds);
            NegotiateSchemeFactory nsf = new NegotiateSchemeFactory();
            httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.SPNEGO, nsf);
            // Create AuthCache instance
            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
            authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);
            // Add AuthCache to the execution context
            BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
            localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
            httpclient = wrapClient(httpclient);

            HttpGet get;
            for (int i = 0; i < port.length; i++) {

                    get = new HttpGet("http://" + ip + ":" + port[i] + "/");

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
                    try {
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename", true));
                        out.write("ip:  "+ ip + " : "+port+ " - " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());  //HTTP status returned off request );
                    } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        }
}
```

My issue thus far has been that it opens the text file, hits a single bad result, doesn't serialize it, then just dies with an exception.

I'm not sure how to make it continue with an exception (I know some sites will say "not up" that's why it's a port scanner.

Any help would be wonderful and would probably save some poor interns from manually checking about 6000 ip's tomorrow.

Comment: Why do you expect to get an HTTP response on ports 21, 23 and 502? And how do you expect to debug your problem if you ignore the exception?  At least print (and post) the stacktrace.

Comment: What exception does it throw ?

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://x.x.x.x:80 refused
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)

Etc etc.   I just want to ignore it, as it will throw whenever a connection is refused.

Comment: Jim is right, you don't expect HTTP let alone HTTP authentication on those ports. You should be checking multiple protocols (e.g. using http://commons.apache.org/net/ ) and authentication schemes. Then followup with the interns on the ones that could not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling exceptions thrown by HttpClient when the connection cannot be made. You should not assume that `httpclient.execute(get)` will always return without exception.

If you want your program to ignore these conditions and keep on trucking, you need to catch these exceptions.

Alternatively, it seems like you might want to give [nmap](http://nmap.org/) a try.

Comment: Nmap has proven to be somewhat unreliable which is a strange thing to say.   I've done a nmap -iL c:\scan.txt -p 21,23,80,502,8080 > results.txt  and ended up with a lot of "bad" (when checked manually they turn out false) results

Answer (score 0):

You don't say in your post, but my guess is it's throwing `ClientProtocolException` on the first request to port 21, which is to be expected as port 21 does not speak HTTP.  You are not catching this exception, so your program dies.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "bad results"?  Cases where nmap said a port was open or closed and it wasn't?

If you do decide to continue down the nmap path and want to integrate nmap with some Java code, have a look at Nmap4j on sourceforge.net. It's a simple Java wrapper around Nmap that allows you to access the results as Java objects.